# how to get list of tasks between 2 tasks in Activiti workfow

Tags: workflow, activiti, bpmn

We are using Activiti workflow to model our workflow process. We have multiple stages in our workflow and we have modeled them using tasks. Between stages, there are multiple tasks.

Is there an API to get the list of tasks that fall between two tasks?

Thanks you

Regards,
Ramki

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct API. You will need to parse the process model.
You can get the process model using the repositoryService bean, you can then parse the xml to retrieve a list of tasks between two known activities.

Not ideal, but it isnt difficult.
Greg

Comment: Thanks for the response